# Find consecutive range in a given list with limit

Tags: java, algorithm

Find the maximum consecutive elements matching the given condition.

I have a list of numbers called A, another list called B and a limit called Limit.

The task is find the maximum k consecutive elements in A such that they satisfy below condition.

> Max(B[i],B[i+1],...B[i+k]) + Sum(A[i], A[i+1], ..., A[i+k]) * k ≤ Limit

**Example:**

> A = [2,1,3,4,5]
> B = [3,6,1,3,4]
> Limit = 25
>
> Take 2 consecutive elements:
> Highest sum occurs with elements in A = 4,5. The corresponding max in B is Max(3,4) = 4.
> So value = 4 + (4+5) * 2 = 22. Here 22 ≤ 25, so 2 consecutive is possible
>
> Take 3 consecutive elements:
> Taking sum for 1st 3 elements of A = 2,1,3. The corresponding max in B is Max(3,6,1) = 6.
> So value = 6 + (2+1+3) * 3 = 24. Here 24 ≤ 25, so 3 consecutive is possible
>
> Take 4 consecutive elements:
> Taking sum for 1st 4 elements of A = 2,1,3,4. The corresponding max in B is Max(3,6,1,3) = 6.
> So value = 6 + (2+1+3+4) * 4 = 46. Here 46 > 25, so 4 consecutive is not possible
>
> So correct answer to this input is 3.

Constraints:
n (Size of A) is up to 10⁵, A elements up to 10¹⁴, B elements up to 10⁹, Limit up to 10¹⁴.

Here is my code:

```
public int getMax(List<Integer> A, List<Integer> B, long limit) {
    int result = 0;
    int n = A.size();
    for(int len=1; len<=n; len++) {
        for(int i=0; i<=n-len; i++) {
            int j=i+len-1;
            int max = B.get(i);
            long total = 0;
            for(int k=i; k<=j; k++) {
                total += A.get(k);
                max = Math.max(max, B.get(k));
            }
            total = max + total * len;
            if(total < limit) {
                result = len;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This code works for smaller range of inputs.
But fails with a time out for larger inputs. How can I reduce time complexity of this code?

**Updated:**

Updated code based on `dratenik` answer, but the sample test case mentioned in my post itself is failing. The program is returning `4` instead of `3`.

```
public int getMax(List<Integer> A, List<Integer> B, long limit) {
    int from = 0, to = 0, max = -1;
    int n = A.size();
    for (; from < n;) {
        int total = 0;
        int m = B.get(from); // updated here
        for (int i = from; i < to; i++) {
            total += A.get(i); // updated here
            m = Math.max(m, B.get(i)); // updated here
        }

        total = m + total * (to - from); // updated here

        if (total <= limit && to - from + 1 > max) {
            max = to - from + 1;
        }
        if (total < limit && to < n) { // below target, extend window
            to++;
        } else { // otherwise contract window
            from++;
        }
        if (from > to) {
            to = from;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: in the example statement you say that limit is 25 but then compare the results against 33

Comment: I guess the problem is in the implementation of the List. List is an interface with several different implementations. What type of List do you hand over?

Comment: @user1984, i have corrected it.

Comment: @TobiasLukoschek, it is ArrayList

Comment: In the attempted implementation of dratenik's algorithm, decide *and document* whether `to` shall be exclusive or inclusive. Check if the implementation follows.

Comment: `What type of List do you hand over` ([Tobias Lukoschek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70245709/find-cosecutive-range-in-a-given-lists-with-limit#comment124175038_70245709)) *Shouldn't* affect correctness (a super-constant `.get()` increases run time). `List<` **`Integer`** `>` is at odds with `A elements up to 10¹⁴`.

Comment: (Updating `m`: if added element is greater, set `m`. If dropped element has value `m`, reestablish.)

Comment: Something quite strange in example data and formula, i want to mention sum() here, does it require Max(sum(A[i]...) if not why the example data show A = 4,5 with consecutive 2

Comment: (Can you explicate what you consider `a reputable source`?)

Comment: What, if any, is the *lower* limit on A element values?

Comment: @huy, here considering the sum of 2 consecutive numbers, so just taking an example of last 2 elements of A which are 4,5

Comment: @learner please be aware of this step, it might lead to different complexity if we have to find max(sum) or any sum ... with max(sum) we have to scan all possibilities, so it will take so much time  with large array of A

Comment: Can there be negative numbers in A or B?  They would make the problem a lot more difficult.  Otherwise you can do this in O(n) time.

Comment: @MattTimmermans, they are always positive.

Comment: From i to i+k is k+1 elements, not k elements.  I'm going to assume you want to stop at i+k-1, since it's consistent with your example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since all the elements of A and B are positive, you can solve this with the usual two-pointer approach to finding a maximum length subarray:

1. Initialize two pointers *s* and *e* to the start of the arrays, and then advance *e* as far as possible without violating the limit.  This finds the longest valid subarray that starts at *s*.
2. While *e* isn't at the end of the arrays, advance *s* by one position, and then again advance *e* as far as possible without violating the limit.  This finds the longest valid subarray that starts at every position.  This leads to an O(n) algorithm, because *e* can advance monotonically.
3. Your answer is the longest valid sequence you see.

In order to determine in O(1) whether or not a particular range from *s* to *e* is valid, you need to track the cumulative sum of A elements and the current maximum of B elements.

The sum is easy -- just add elements that *e* passes and subtract elements that *s* passes.

To track the current maximum of elements in B, you can use the standard sliding-window-maximum algorithm described here: [Sliding window maximum in O(n) time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212532/sliding-window-maximum-in-on-time/57213522#57213522).  It works just fine with expanding and contracting windows, maintaining O(1) amortized cost per operation.

Here's an O(n) solution in Java.  Note that I multiplied the sum of A elements by the length of the sequence, because it's what you seem to intend, even though the formula you wrote multiplies by length-1:

```
public static int getMax(List<Integer> A, List<Integer> B, long limit) {
    final int size = A.size();
    // a Queue containing indexes of elements that may become max in the window
    // they must be monotonically decreasing
    final int maxQ[] = new int[size];
    int maxQstart = 0, maxQend = 0;
    // current valid window start and end
    int s=0, e = 0;
    int bestLen = 0;
    long windowSum = 0;
    while (s < size && e < size) {
        // calculate longer window max
        long nextMax = maxQstart < maxQend ? B.get(maxQ[maxQstart]) : 0;
        nextMax = Math.max(nextMax, B.get(e));
        long sumPart = (windowSum + A.get(e)) * (e+1-s);
        if (nextMax + sumPart <= limit) {
            // extending the window is valid
            int lastB = B.get(e);
            while (maxQstart < maxQend && B.get(maxQ[maxQend-1]) <= lastB) {
                --maxQend;
            }
            maxQ[maxQend++] = e;
            windowSum += A.get(e);
            ++e;
            if (e-s > bestLen) {
                bestLen = e-s;
            }
        } else if (e > s) {
            // extending the window is invalid.
            // move up the start instead
            windowSum -= A.get(s);
            ++s;
            while(maxQstart < maxQend && maxQ[maxQstart] < s) {
                ++maxQstart;
            }
        } else {
            // we need to move the start up, but the window is empty, so move them both
            ++s;
            ++e;
        }
    }
    return bestLen;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sliding window approach? Slightly pseudocodey version:

```
int from=0, to=0, max = -1;
for(;from<n;) {
    total = (target expression on elements between from-to inclusive)
    if (total<=target && to-from+1 > max) {max = to-from+1;}
    if (total<target && to<n) { // below target, extend window
        to++;
    } else { // otherwise contract window
        from++;
    }
    if (from>to) {to=from;}
}
return max;
```

The sum could be updated incrementally, but I don't know how to sensibly update the `max(B[i],B[i+1],...B[i+k])` part when contracting the window, so let's recompute the whole thing at each step.

Comment: I tried your logic, I have updated my post also with my code, it is giving output as 4 instead of 3 for the test case I have given.

Comment: @learner This code is different from yours only in that from-to is inclusive here, while yours is mixed inclusive and exclusive. The logic and code here should work if you fix that. It's still `O(n^2)`; you can get `O(n lg n)` by not recomputing the sum from scratch and tracking the max in a priority queue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use meanigful names to make the code readable. Don't hesitate to ask where it is not clear:

```
public int getMax(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b, long limit) {

    int max = -1;
    int numberOfElements = 2;
    boolean found;

    do{
        found = false;
        for ( int index = 0; index <= a.size() - numberOfElements; index++) {
            int totalA = 0;
            int maxB = b.get(index);
            for (int i = index; i < index + numberOfElements; i++) {
                totalA += a.get(i);
                maxB = Math.max(maxB,b.get(i)); // updated here
            }

            int total = maxB + totalA * numberOfElements;

            if (total <= limit && numberOfElements >= max) {
                max = numberOfElements;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        numberOfElements++;

    } while(found && numberOfElements <= a.size());

    return max;
}
```

(more test cases can be helpful for further debugging)

Comment: Is this code also have the time complexity of Order of N power 3?

Comment: Does it work as expected ?

Comment: No, still failing for large inputs saying timeout, but I don't have the test cases for those.

Comment: How can I reproduce this problem  ?

Comment: Try adding `break;`  after `found = true;`

Comment: As my task is `maximum k consecutive elements in A` if we break the loop, then it stops at first occurrence itself so the result will not be correct.

Comment: If `found = true;` for a certain `numberOfElements` (k) use `break` to test the next `numberOfElements`. I'll post a modified faster version.

Comment: The posted code processes lists of 75500  elements in ~ 7 seconds

Answer (score 1):

I think the main obstacle there is how to efficiently track maximum over sliding window.

Easy optimization in this respect without diving into dynamic programming is to make use of [MaxHeap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).
In java it is implemented as [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

Please consider following code.

```
    private int findMaxRange(List<Long> listA, List<Long> listB, long limit) {
        int maxRange = 0;
        while (maxRange < listA.size() && isRangePossible(listA, listB, limit, maxRange+1)) {
            maxRange++;
        }
        return maxRange;
    }

    private boolean isRangePossible(List<Long> listA, List<Long> listB, long limit, int rangeSize) {

        //calculate initial values of max and sum
        PriorityQueue<Long> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(rangeSize, Comparator.reverseOrder());
        listB.stream().limit(rangeSize).forEach(maxHeap::add);
        Long max = maxHeap.peek();
        Long sum = listA.stream().limit(rangeSize).mapToLong(i->i).sum();

        //iterate with sliding window
        for (int i = 0; i < listA.size() - rangeSize; i++) {
            if (isConditionMet(max, sum, rangeSize, limit)) {
                return true;
            }

            sum = sum + listA.get(i+rangeSize) - listA.get(i);

            maxHeap.remove(listB.get(i));
            maxHeap.add(listB.get(i+rangeSize));
            max = maxHeap.peek();
        }

        return isConditionMet(max, sum, rangeSize, limit);
    }

    private boolean isConditionMet(Long max, Long sum, int rangeSize, long limit) {
        return max + sum * rangeSize < limit;
    }
```

Also please pay attention to value ranges. Such big values can easily overflow long and may require specialized types like BigInteger. You should also consider how much memory is used by auxiliary datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be use of three nested `for` loops for calculating `max` and sum for every window.

We can avoid this unnecessary iterations by using calculations of previous iteration in the new iteration with the help of [Dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

In my solution, I made 2 2d `Array`s, one to store max values for each windows and other to store sums for each windows, storing values of previous iterations will greatly reduce the time complexity.

here is the Java code:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        
        List A = Arrays.asList(2,1,3,4,5);
        List B = Arrays.asList(3,6,1,3,4);
        
        
        System.out.println(MyClass.getMax(A, B, 25L));
    }
    
    public static int getMax(List<Integer> A, List<Integer> B, long limit) {
        int n = A.size();
    
        int[][] dp1 = new int[n + 1][n + 1];
        int[][] dp2 = new int[n + 1][n + 1];

        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for(int j = i; j <= n; j++) {
                dp1[i][j] = Math.max(dp1[i - 1][j- 1], B.get(j - 1));
                
                dp2[i][j] = dp2[i - 1][j- 1] + A.get(j - 1);
            }
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
                System.out.print("{" + dp1[i][j] + ", " + dp2[i][j] + "}, ");
            }
            System.out.println();            
        }
        
        int kMax = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            for(int j = i; j <= n; j++) {
                if(dp1[i][j] + dp2[i][j] * i <= limit) {
                    kMax = i;
                }
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Max K: " + kMax);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are dependent only on algorithms and not making any app or game, it's not necessary that you have to use java, try using `python` or `c++` (or even `c`, `c#`), python is used mostly for algorithms,

or if you need java only then add breakpoints or make the program to print all work it does (ask it to print `j`, `i`, `k`, `result` variables in console) then you can easily debug.