# Incremental algorithm for maximum of last N entries in a series

Tags: algorithm, max, min

Does anyone know of an efficient incremental algorithm for the maximum (or minimum) of the last *n* entries of an array?

By "efficient" and "incremental" I mean that when a new element is added to the array we do something smarter than just searching the last *n* entries for the maximum! Ideally it should be constant complexity O(1) with respect to *n* (and certainly < O(*n*)). Obviously each array entry can store one or more data to aid in the calculation. The computed maximum must be available for all array entries, not just the last entry.

Thanks

Comment: Using a balanced tree you can keep the last N entries sorted, inserting the new entry and removing the N + 1 has complexity O(log N)

Comment: are elements only added to the array or does the algorithm need to be able to efficiently remove elements from the array too?

Comment: I suggest posting some API to show which operations you want to support. Particularly, "must be available for all array entries" is unclear to me. But other things may be unclear to others, so I think desired API would be great.

Comment: No feed-back from the Asker...

Comment: The usual sliding-window-maximum algorithm is amortized constant time per item: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212532/sliding-window-maximum-in-on-time/57213522#57213522

Comment: Elements only added at the end. No removals required. API: (1) void computeMaxLastN(int n, T[] array) where T has slots in which you can store the results and any intermediate calculations. (2) T getMaxLastN(T[] array, int indexGreaterThanN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea that gives you the min and max of the last n elements of the array in constant time and adding new elements is of `O(log n)` time complexity.

1. Have a min and a max heap where you keep the last `n` elements of the array. These elements need to be nodes which you can reference later.
2. Have a queue in the form of a linked list or any data structure where FIFO operations are of constant time complexity. Keep track of the last `n` elements in this queue. Each element of the queue holds a reference to the corresponding entries in the min and max heaps.
3. Whenever a new element is added to the array do the following:

- Add it to the min and max heaps: `log n` operations.
- Enque the refernces to this new element in the queue: constant operation.
- Deque the reference of the element that goes out of the `n` length window from the queue: constant operation.
- remove that element from the min and max heap: `log n` operation.

The min and max heaps give you the current min and max elements of the last `n` elements at any time in constant time.

One possible optimization that wouldn't change the time complexity though is to combine the delete and add operations to a heap into one step. What you are going to do is to update the value of the reference that you want to delete from the heap with the value of the new element. Then run a swim and sink operation for the heap to hold its invariant. Then you will enque the dequed reference into the queue again, because it now holds the most recent value in the `n` length window.

Comment: I don't understand you point @YvesDaoust Please explain, I genuinely would like to learn.

Comment: Understand the sentence in reverse.

Comment: I selected as the answer ... though the explanation in the selected answer linked to by Matt Timmermans [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212532/sliding-window-maximum-in-on-time?noredirect=1&lq=1) is slightly clearer.

Comment: Thank you for the link @barneypitt I missed that. Going to read and learn from it :D

Comment: Note that there is nothing wrong with Yves Daoust's answer! But the Deque-based solution is more intuitive (to me) and somewhat easier to implement (ergo less likely to have bugs!), so I've opted for simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

You are lucky, there is a cool algorithm due to van Herk, Gil and Werman that computes a 1D dilation in constant time per element.

https://tpgit.github.io/UnOfficialLeptDocs/leptonica/grayscale-morphology.html

It can be made online with a buffer of 2N-1 elements.

The idea is simple. If you want to compute the maxima of four successive elements, you can compute incrementally the following maxima: `a`, `ab`, `abc`, `abcd` and `e`, `ef`, `efg`, `efgh`. Now combine...

```
abcd
 bcd e
  cd ef
   d efg
```

and repeat with the following elements.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but how do you incrementally compute the right-hand terms? If the next term is `h`, I don't see how to make `f`, `fg`, `fgh` incrementally.

Comment: Actually, I don't see how the algorithm works at all.  Can you explain?

Comment: Okay, h is easy: You would compute `efgh = max(efg, h)`; but how to continue with `i`? You would have to combine it with `fgh`, which is not available.

Comment: @PaulHankin: the diagram shows how to compute four maxima, from abcd to defg, from the elements abcdefg, using 8 comparisons (more generally N maxima with 3N-4 comparisons). Now repeat the same pattern with efghijk.

Comment: @PaulHankin: or read the link.

Comment: Okay, I skimmed through the description. Add to the answer another 5th line: ` efgh` [My description, the answer and the link all describe a similar, but not identical distribution of the letters.] Calculate the 8 maxima with 6 comparisons. Combine left and right side for the three middle lines with 3 comparisons. You get 5 maxima with length 4 with 9 comparisons or 1.8 comparisons/maximum of 4 elements. After those 5 start completely new.

Comment: @Sebastian: efgh can be computed with the next block, like abcd was. The ratio is 3 comparisons per maximum (asymptotically).

Comment: Your example achieves 2 comparisons/maximum of 4, which is a bit worse than 1.8. I think the link has some errors with the width of the indices. (It demands odd L, and the very first maximum goes from 0 to L and calculates the maximum of L+1 elements).

Comment: @Sebastian: the exact ratio is 3-4/N. This is unimportant. What matters is O(1), not counting that the algorithm is extremely simple.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm not sure that I completely understand: you first compute d, cd, bcd, abcd; with this you can process e, f, g, h, in O(1), then you again compute h, gh, fgh, efgh, and so on (then each element is processed in constant amortized time), is this correct?

Comment: Very good algorithm with combining left and right and it has O(1). Nevertheless I am quite sure that the author got confused with indices starting with 0 or 1.

Comment: @Rocco You compute the triangles on the left side in O(N), the triangles on the right side in O(N) and combine the fitting left and right maximum in O(N) and have calculated about N maxima in O(3N)=O(N) time resulting in an average time of O(1). On average you need less than 3 comparisons per maximum over N elements.

Comment: The left-hand part isn't incremental -- none of those sums can be calculated without `d`.  An on-line implementation that requires the sum of the last N after each item is added takes O(N) per item with this approach.  Better to use the standard algorithm.

Comment: I understand that, but the OP doesn't want to buffer 2N-1 values before getting any results.

Comment: Oh, yes. The first maximums are `a`, `ab`, `abc`, `abcd`, which you can produce incrementally, but then you have to throw away the first 3 and generate `bcd`, `cd`, and `d`.  You're right it's still O(1) amortized, and you can make it real-time O(1) with an N sample delay, just like the standard algorithm.

Comment: I'm convinced that this is as good as the standard algorithm.  SO is whining about too many comments, so probably not a good idea to carry on.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. Here is my Java implementation of the Deque-based algorithm (

```
import java.util.*;

/**
 *  Calculation is exclusive, i.e. immediately after adding an entry, the entry is not under consideration for min/max. <br>
 *
 *  Algorith outline: <br>
 *     at every step: <br>
 *    <br>
 *       if (!Deque.Empty) and (Deque.Head.Index <= CurrentIndex - T) then        <br>
 *          Deque.ExtractHead;                                                    <br>
 *       //Head is too old, it is leaving the window                              <br>
 *                                                                                <br>
 *       while (!Deque.Empty) and (Deque.Tail.Value > CurrentValue) do            <br>
 *          Deque.ExtractTail;                                                    <br>
 *       //remove elements that have no chance to become minimum in the window    <br>
 *                                                                                <br>
 *       Deque.AddTail(CurrentValue, CurrentIndex);                               <br>
 *       CurrentMin = Deque.Head.Value                                            <br>
 *       //Head value is minimum in the current window                            <br>
 */
public class RollingMinMax {

    private static class Entry {
        final int index;
        final double value;

        private Entry(int index, double value) {
            this.index = index;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Entry{");
            sb.append("index=").append(index);
            sb.append(", value=").append(value);
            sb.append('}');
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
    
    private final ArrayDeque<Entry> _minQueue;
    private final ArrayDeque<Entry> _maxQueue;
    private final int _windowSizeMin;
    private final int _windowSizeMax;
    private int _count= 0;
    private ArrayList<Double> _minHistory;
    private ArrayList<Double> _maxHistory;

    public RollingMinMax(int windowSizeMin, int windowSizeMax, boolean keepHistories) {
        _windowSizeMin = windowSizeMin;
        _windowSizeMax = windowSizeMax;
        if (_windowSizeMin < 0 || _windowSizeMax < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("window size(s) too small");
        }
        _minQueue = new ArrayDeque<>(windowSizeMin);
        _maxQueue = new ArrayDeque<>(windowSizeMax);
        if (keepHistories) {
            _minHistory = new ArrayList<>();
            _maxHistory = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    public void add(double datum) {
        final Entry entry = new Entry(_count, datum);

        // remove entriesthat are too old for consideration
        while (!_minQueue.isEmpty() && _minQueue.getFirst().index < _count - _windowSizeMin) {
            _minQueue.removeFirst();
        }
        while (!_maxQueue.isEmpty() && _maxQueue.getFirst().index < _count - _windowSizeMax) {
            _maxQueue.removeFirst();
        }

        // remove entries too small/large
        while (!_minQueue.isEmpty() && _minQueue.getLast().value > datum) {
            _minQueue.removeLast();
        }
        while (!_maxQueue.isEmpty() && _maxQueue.getLast().value < datum) {
            _maxQueue.removeLast();
        }

        enqueueCurrent(entry);

        ++_count;

        if (_minHistory != null) {
            _minHistory.add(getMin());
            _maxHistory.add(getMax());
        }

    }

    private void enqueueCurrent(Entry entry) {
        _minQueue.addLast(entry);
        _maxQueue.addLast(entry);
    }

    /** Double.NaN returned if not enough data added yet to compute. */
    public double getMin() {
        if (_count <= _windowSizeMin) {
            return Double.NaN;
        }
        double result = _minQueue.getFirst().value;
        return result;
    }

    public double getMax() {
        if (_count <= _windowSizeMax) {
            return Double.NaN;
        }
        double result = _maxQueue.getFirst().value;
        return result;
    }

    private ArrayList<Double> getMinHistory() {
        return _minHistory;
    }

    private ArrayList<Double> getMaxHistory() {
        return _maxHistory;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "RollingMinMax[" + _windowSizeMin + ", "+ _windowSizeMax + "] min = " + getMin() + ", max =" + getMax() + ", count = " + _count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] ignored) {
        final ArrayList<Double> data = (ArrayList<Double>) Arrays.asList(
            1d, 4d, 6d,  0d, 9d, 5d, 3d, 6d, 8d, 10d, 13d, 15d, 8d, 14d, 12d, 5d, 6d, 8d, 10d, 7d, 5d, 3d, 2d
        );

        RollingMinMax calculator = new RollingMinMax(4, 6, true);
        System.out.println("calculator = " + calculator);

        int index = 0;
        for (double datum : data) {
            calculator.add(datum);
            System.out.println(index + "\t data=" + datum + ", min=" + calculator.getMin() + ", max=" +calculator.getMax());
            ++index;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Having read your solution and the one you linked I realized that using a monotonic queue this can be done in `O(1)` while my solution is logarithmic and much more complex. I had seen this before and even implemented it but didn't think of it when I was answering the question. Learned a lesson today.